# How to attach element to head DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have Iframe :

```
<iframe src="http://localhost/data/mapset/WEBLAYOUT"
        id="iframeMgMap"
        frameborder="0"
        scrolling="no"
        width="100%"
        onload=""
        height="800px"></iframe>
```

The iframe's DOM that how it looks in Elements section in debugger window:

```
<frameset id="mainFrame">
  <frameset id="secondaryFrame">
    <frameset id="firstpanel">
      <frame id="taskArea">
        #document
       <head>"some conent"<head></frame>
    </frameset>
  </frameset>
```

My question is how can I get head element inside frame with id="taskArea".
And attach to it this element:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../viewerfiles/viewer.css" type="text/css">
```

Comment: Why oh why have a frameset in an iframe? Also are they from the same origin? You want to insert your stylesheet in the taskArea frame's document?

Comment: @mplungjan yes I want to insert stylesheet in the taskArea frame's document

Comment: And are all the files from the same domain/port/etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery:

```
var iframe = $('#iframeMgMap').contents();
var taskArea = iframe.find('#taskArea');
taskArea.append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="../viewerfiles/viewer.css" type="text/css">');
```

Cheers